# Using underscore groupby to group an array of cars by their colour

Tags: javascript, iterator, underscore.js

I have an array of cars.

```
car = {
    make: "nissan",
    model: "sunny",
    colour: "red"
};
```

How would I use underscore.js to group the array by colour?

I've tried a few combos but I'm not really sure how to specify my iterator condition:

```
var carsGroupedByColor = _.groupBy(cars, false, colour);
var carsGroupedByColor = _.groupBy(vars, false, function(cars){ return cars[colour]; };
```

They all return everything in the array each time.

Comment: you state you want to group by make but then group by colour in your examples? which one do you want? also the variable redCars suggests you actually want to filter the list rather than group it?

Comment: @Jon Taylor, thats a good point you make about filtering instead of group by.  I have updated the question for consitency

Comment: im still a little confused with your variable name redCars unless you plan to select the red cars group from the grouped by statement?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need the `false` second argument, the following will work:

```
var redCars = _.groupBy(cars, 'colour');
```

Note that the second parameter can either be a `function` or a `string`. If it's a `string` Underscore groups by that property name.

Taken from the docs:

> Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each
>   value through **iterator**. If **iterator** is a string instead of a function,
>   groups by the property named by **iterator** on each of the values.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JpPjA/).

Comment: I am confused as to which he wants since he asked for the make to be grouped, yet his examples and your answer group by colour.  Out of interest is the first of my two answers correct? if not I will remove that part.

Comment: @JonTaylor both of yours are correct :) Good point about grouping about make, will update my answer. I was confused too as OP asked for make but then the examples are by colour.

Comment: The other thing is that the variable redCars suggests he wants to filter rather than group? unless of course you do this? var redCars = _.groupBy(cars, 'colour')["red"]; Or something along those lines (im not good with javascript objects)

Comment: that's valid JS syntax. If he wants to get a specific colour out then that example is correct.

Comment: While the syntax of this answer is correct, the `redCars` variable is actually an object containing all colours. The red cars would be available at `redCars.red`.

Answer (score 11):

I've never used underscore js but would it not be as per their docs

```
var groupedCars = _.groupBy(cars, function(car) { return car.make; });
```

In fact I believe this ir more correct since it states that if the iterator is a string instead it groups by the property in the object with that string name.

```
var groupedCars = _.groupBy(cars, "make");
```

If you then want just the red cars (even though you really should be using a filter I guess) then you can do the following

```
var redCars = groupedCars["red"];
```

To use a filter instead

> Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (iterator). Delegates to the native filter method, if it exists.

```
var redCars = _.filter(cars, function(car) { return car.colour == "red" });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "jim",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "33"
    },
    {
        "name": "eddie",
        "color": "green",
        "age": "77"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dheeraj",
        "color": "blue",
        "age": "25"
    },
    {
        "name": "Suraj",
        "color": "green",
        "age": "25"
    }
];

var result = _.groupBy(data,"color");
console.log(result);
```